# Make 'File Upload' optional in Upload Form - .NET

Tags: .net, file, upload, mappath

Right now, I'm using this to allow a file to be moved to our server:

`filUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filUpload.FileName));`

However when I **don't** upload a file, it gives me an error:

`System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\**\**\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\**\Images\'.`

How do I make the file upload optional so users don't have to upload a file?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if `filUpload.FileName` is not empty. Only upload if it isn't.

.NET 4.0:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filUpload.FileName))
{
  filUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filUpload.FileName));
}
```

.NET < 4.0:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filUpload.FileName))
{
  filUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filUpload.FileName));
}
```

Comment: D'oh. In hindsight, that makes a lot of sense. Many thanks, Oded for such a speedy and helpful reply.